# Error Integrating Inmobi in Android App

Tags: android, inmobi

I am integrating inmobi in my android app. I have placed following code in my xml file :-

```
<com.inmobi.ads.InMobiBanner
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/banner"
    ads:placementId="1474202520715"
    ads:refreshInterval="60"
    />
```

I have initialized by main activity as :-

```
InMobiSdk.init(MainActivity.this, "df19afdaf27f4fb4a2c2b85e2c10bc6a");
       InMobiBanner bannerAd =(InMobiBanner) findViewById(R.id.banner);
```

It is giving me error in placementID and refreshInterval as "No resource identifier found for attribute 'placementId'".

Can any one help me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

to

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.inmobi.ads.InMobiBanner"
```